# Excel VBA Conditional Combination Counter Summary

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which will create all 3 number combinations of a set of numbers that are in cells A1 and below in a list (eg. 1,2,3,4,5,6) ;

```
Sub Three_combo()
Dim Last As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim g, h, i, j, k, l
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To Last - 2
            For j = i + 1 To Last - 1
                For k = j + 1 To Last
                Cells(l + 1, 2) = Cells(i, 1) & "." & Cells(j, 1) & "." _
                & Cells(k, 1)
                l = l + 1
                Next
            Next
        Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Then I have modified the code below to say that if the first number of the combination is equal to 1 then print the combination otherwise iterate to the next combination. In the end it will list all items that start with 1. What I would like to do is instead of printing out each iteration of the combination, is to print a summary at the end that will count the number of times i was true and show a summary like "i = 10". Any suggestions ?

```
Sub Three_Combo1()
Dim Last As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim g, h, i, j, k, l

Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To Last - 2
            For j = i + 1 To Last - 1
                For k = j + 1 To Last
                
                If i = 1 Then
                
                Cells(l + 1, 2) = Cells(i, 1) & "." & Cells(j, 1) & "." _
                & Cells(k, 1)
                l = l + 1
                Else
                l = l + 1
                End If
                
                Next
            Next
        Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will print the result to the console. For input `1,2,3,4` it prints `Count Ones: 3`

```
Sub Three_Combo_count()
   Dim Last As Long
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Dim g, h, i, j, k, l
   Dim countOnes As Long

   Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   For i = 1 To Last - 2
      For j = i + 1 To Last - 1
         For k = j + 1 To Last

         If i = 1 Then countOnes = countOnes + 1
         
         l = l + 1
         Next
      Next
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Debug.Print ("Count Ones: " & CStr(countOnes))
End Sub
```